# Sharing electron applications

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I am trying to publish and share my electron app by using electron packager.
I was following this tutorial:

https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

The tutorial makes a folder 'release-builds' with the application. When I do the same, everything works perfectly from that folder.

When I try to share the application, sending it via whatever means, (zipped, dropbox etc.) the application never runs from those folder, so I can't share my app.

When trying to share it, the app opens but the backend in the application never responds.

Here's me package.json.

Does anyone have any ideas how to successfully share Electron apps?

```js
{
    "name": "electron-gara",
    "productName": "Application",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "author": "Me",
    "dependencies": {
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "xlsx": {
            "version": "^0.11.6"
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^1.7.9",
        "electron-packager": "^9.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "package-win": "electron-packager . Gara-application --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/gara.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Gára Application\""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should package it into a .exe

At the bottom of that article there's a link for [`Windows installer tutorial.`](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-windows-installer/) that should help you make a .exe that you can share with others.